# Kinesis timing out when invoked via Lambda but code hasn't changed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

So I am encountering a weird situation where Kinesis is timing out on me when I invoke putRecord from my Lambda function. The weird part about all this is that it worked for me earlier this morning, but it doesn't work for me now. The code has not changed and it's the same zip file before. Has anyone encountered a situation like this before?

Comment: Have you changed any settings or anything since the last time it worked? Enabled VPC access on your Lambda function perhaps?

Comment: no, didn't do that

Comment: Sorry I just want to give an update. My issue is fixed...without me doing anything. In fact I'm not sure if changes were even made. I tried to create a new lambda function and did the same thing and it still gave the same timeout error. I deleted that lambda function and went back to my original lambda function and tested it again with no new changes and it just works. Refreshed the page and tested multiple times and it just works. No timeout error.


However under Event Sources in my Lambda, my Kinesis Details showed this message: "PROBLEM: Function call failed".

Comment: It's normal behavior if calls to AWS service throttled by Amazon.
Have you looked on CloudWatch metrics of Lambda function and Kinesis stream? Pay particular attention on 'throttled' counters.

Comment: I don't see throttled in CloudWatch for Kinesis, but I do see the filter for it in Lambda. There are no throttles by the Lambda. I put a console.log in my Lambda function before Kinesis is called and I put a console.log in putRecord's callback. Only the console.log before the Kinesis call was triggered. So it must have timed out in Kinesis. I have also tried to create a new Kinesis stream, but it had the same result.

Comment: Dear Jeff, have you ever gained a better understanding of why putRecord timed out here? Were having the exact same issue with random timeouts that are increasing steadily since February. After days of investigating we still have no clue. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a good option to reuse the TCP connections, it will improve your connections to AWS services as internally all of them are just simple https connections.

Add this environment variable:

```
AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED = 1
```